# R: efficient ways to add months to dates?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data.table of millions of rows and one of the columns is date column. I would like to add 12 months to all the dates in that column and create a new column. So I use the dplyr and lubridate packages E.g.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
new_data <- data %>% mutate(date12m = date %m+% months(12))
```

This works, however it is very slow for large datasets. Am I missing something? How can this be sped up? I generally don't expect R to run for more than 10 minutes for such a simple task

**Edit:**

I note that my solution is already more efficient than using as.yearmon. Thanks to Colonel Beauvel for the solution

```
a <- data.frame(date = rep(today(),1000000))


func = function(u) {
  d = as.Date(as.yearmon(u)+1, frac=1) 
  if(day(u)>day(d)) return(d)
  day(d) = day(u)
  d
} 

pt <- proc.time()
a <- a %>% mutate(date12m = func(date))
data.table::timetaken(pt)


pt <- proc.time()
a <- a %>% mutate(date12m = date %m+% 12)
data.table::timetaken(pt)
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a small part of your data?

Comment: hope the answer help, you need to convert the wanted columns in dates before applying my function.

Comment: I agree that this should be faster, but it's not really a simple task given that dates are stored as seconds since jan 1 1970

Answer (score 5):

Just add 1 with `month`:

```
x=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2007-01-01"), to=as.Date("2014-12-12"), by="day")
month(x) = month(x) + 1

#> head(x)
#[1] "2007-02-01" "2007-02-02" "2007-02-03" "2007-02-04" "2007-02-05" "2007-02-06"
```

**Edit** : as per @akrun comment here is the solution, using `as.yearmon` from `zoo` package. The trick is to do quick check when taking the day of the last date of the next month:

```
library(zoo)

func = function(u)
{
    d = as.Date(as.yearmon(u)+1/12, frac=1) 
    if(day(u)>day(d)) return(d)
    day(d) = day(u)
    d
} 

x=as.Date(c("2014-01-31","2015-02-28","2013-03-02"))
#> as.Date(sapply(x, func))
#[1] "2014-02-28" "2015-03-28" "2013-04-02"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it would be better if you show some benchmarks as te OP wants an efficient code.  From my benchmarks, OP's solution is efficient when compared to `mondate`.  Not checked yours though:-)

Comment: I get the warning message while applying to a test dataset. `In if (day(u) > day(d)) return(d) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: what is your dataset? I do not have this message at all. It means day(u) is a vector which should not be the case.

Comment: My understanding was that your code can be applied as `data %>% mutate(date12m = func(date))`  But based on your example, is it again looped by `sapply`?

Comment: The dataset is `set.seed(24);
 data <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'), length.out=20, by='1 month'), val=rnorm(20))`

Comment: Based on some benchmarks for 1e6 data using `Col <- function() {data %>% mutate(date12m = func(date))}; xiao <- function() {data %>% mutate(date12m = date %m+% months(12))}` your function takes more time.

Comment: My function is not vectorized. It is not again looped with sapply ...I use sapply once to loop over the vector I want to upgrade by `1M`. But yeah it is quite slow on my dataset. `x=seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2015-01-01"), by="day")` (30 seconds)

Comment: @akrun. Yep I think my original solution is more efficient a <- data.frame(date = rep(today(),1000000))

pt <- proc.time()
a <- a %>% mutate(date12m = func(date))
data.table::timetaken(pt)


pt <- proc.time()
a <- a %>% mutate(date12m = date %m+% 12)
data.table::timetaken(pt)

Answer (score 2):

I am also working with big data frames in R, you can use the package `DescTools`, it has a function named **AddMonths(date,NoOfMonths)**.

It works quite well for me.

```
> a <- ymd("2011-09-9")
> b <- AddMonths(a,1)
> b

[1] "2011-10-09"
```

Comment: Works on data frames. seq doesn't work on data frames. you need make some adjustment before you can use it on data frames. AddMonths is quite straight forward.

Comment: how to apply to a dataframe. It seems to be very slow at that!!